# Remove script filename from url in silex

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, silex

I'm trying to remove from the URL bar the index.php script name with htaccess. This is my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But still the index.php in the URL like this:
https://website.com/index.php/url and need to be moved to https://website.com/url

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved using this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```